# QGIS - Overlay_Intersects with largest overlap

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have the below expression which assigns lines in a line layer to polygons which intersect, but when these links exist across two polygons, I want to return the value of the polygon that the line intersects with the most?

```
overlay_intersects('linelayer', "Match")[0]
```